# ERROR ON HANDEL AsyncFileUpload1 OnClientUploadComplete EVENT and OnClientUploadError event ON PAGE LOAD

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
AsyncFileUpload1.OnClientUploadComplete  = New EventHandler(Of AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)(**AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete**) 

AsyncFileUpload1.OnClientUploadError  = New EventHandler(Of AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)(**AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedFileError**)
```

getting error like as below quota:

> " Delegate 'System.EventHandler(Of
>   AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)' requires an 'AddressOf'
>   expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its
>   constructor. "

Comment: Find Solution it's done thx

Comment: `AddHandler AsyncFileUpload1.UploadedComplete, New EventHandler(Of AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)(AddressOf AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete)`

`AddHandler AsyncFileUpload1.UploadedFileError, New EventHandler(Of AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)(AddressOf AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedFileError)`